# SSIS export to flat file - how to configure all DataTypes for columns w/o manual entry?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

In my OLE DB Source to Flat File Destination Data Flow, I have quite a few columns and it's excruciating to manually set each one to decimal with a scale of 4.

I tried adjusting my SQL code in the OLE DB Source to CAST to decimal(14,4) to see if SSIS would pick that up in Suggest Types, but it likes single-byte signed integer.  I don't see any option to set default column DataTypes.  Is there another way - either by adjusting my SQL code, or within SSIS options - to get all of my columns to decimal, scale 4?

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is *simply* to create a Flat File have you considered using BCP.EXE to Bulk Copy your data out. [Bulk Import and Export of Data (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937.aspx) gives a link to the bcp utility.

You do need to give directions on how to interpret the data.  Here at [Create a Format File (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx) you can examine the two Format File type used to define the data format.  (Naturally.)

The format file that I use is a **Non-XML Format File**.  This is just a text file and is fairly easy to type and make changes within.  For me, this is a quick way to export a flat file. (Of course, if you read further down the page you will see an **XML Format File**, which might be more your style.)

It is also possible to use BCP to copy data back into a SQL Server and it is pretty fast.  (However **BULK INSERT** tends to be a bit faster for importing data.)

So BCP is fast, fairly easy, and comes in two flavors.